# Override em font-size when elements are nested

Tags: css, overriding, font-size

How do you override the font-size property when you have nested elements? Using *!important* doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
div {
    font-size:6em;  
}
p {
    font-size:1em !important;
}
span {

    font-size:1em;
}
```

-

```
<html>
<body>
    <div><span>span</span><p>paragraph</p></div>
</body>
</html>​
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/dvUTQ/

Comment: Hm... it works if you use pixel sizes, but you want it specifically with em sizes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Em's are relative sizes to their parent elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/dvUTQ/3/

```
div#small {
  font-size:2em; 
}
div#big {
  font-size:6em;
}
p {
  font-size:.5em; /* effective sizes: big: 3em, small: 1em */
}
span {
  font-size:2em; /* effective sizes: big: 12em, small: 4em */
}
```

Setting a child element to 1em just makes it the same size as its parent. .5em on p in this case would effectively make it 3em.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [dmzza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12453377/880619): The [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules) rule only has effect when you have selectors in your style sheet with conflicting [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).

In your case there was no conflict, so the `!important` rule couldn't have any effect.

When you have conflicting specificity it is always better to create a more specific selector for the exception.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the CSS3 rem unit, which is relative to the root, not the parent. I've been stuck in this same dilema as the project I'm working on has so many nested elements that the em is not reliable.

You can find more information here http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem.

The only issue is fallback browser support for IE8 and below. You still need to provide a pixel size before declaring the rem size. Despite this extra coding, it may still be worth looking into.

Comment: For reference, the CSS3 spec for the `rem` unit can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#rem-unit.