# Strange behavior on div/child with font-size 0 (zero)

Tags: html, css

To [**avoid an undesired :hover gap between lines**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164793/undesired-hover-gap-between-lines) I did set the container with `font-size:0`. It was working fine but later I found 2 issues.

[**Here's a jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/28wdwLzp/) to illustrate how the container appears when `font-size: 1em` is set. **It's everything fine**.

But [**check this other jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rtwacgv1/): when I set the container with `font-size: 0em` I get **2 unwanted issues**:

[image: issue picture]

**1** - Theres a gap between the top of the page and the container.

**2** - Even with its own font-size, the inner text disappears.

So, my question is: **Why does it happens and how can I fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause for the gap is two properties

```
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
```

If you change it as follows

```
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
```

It will solve your issue.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/rtwacgv1/1/)

**Font-display-issue**

- [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/rtwacgv1/2/)
- [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453324/override-em-font-size-when-elements-are-nested)

Answer (score 1):

It's because the unit "em" is relative to its parent. If you change it to "px" that will solve the problem.

Comment: well this is crazy...its not a `em` problem its about `display:inline-block`. Here is a fiddle link where i changed `em` to `px` and still not working https://jsfiddle.net/yudi/rtwacgv1/4/

Comment: @GauravAggarwal you need to set a bigger font size like 16px, then will become visible. [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tr1gxpq1/)

Comment: but why would you set the font-size to 16px if you dont want the text to display

Comment: @GauravAggarwal the `font-size:0` is to kill the white space on the parent div. The inner text of the child must appear. Sorry if the question wasnt clear enought;

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this two ways. Well i saw it n number of time with display inline-block if there is blank element there is gap on top you can remove it with `vertical-align:top` property.

**CSS**

```
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  outline: 2px dashed black;
  font-size: 0em;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/yudi/28wdwLzp/1/

Although if you only want to disable the text i would like to use `text-indent` css property. This is a proper way to remove text

**CSS**

```
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  outline: 2px dashed black;
  font-size: 1em;
}
#text {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2em;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;  
  text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

fiddle link for this https://jsfiddle.net/yudi/rtwacgv1/3/

Comment: Hello @GauravAggarwal on the current minimal example `vertical-align:top` is enought but the complete scenario have [**this situation**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164793/undesired-hover-gap-between-lines) where a font size equal to zero was needed to avoid the `:hover` gaps between the lines;

Comment: in this question `#container` is having `display:inline-block` css property so there is not probelm...sometimes we have to change the code of nature because of different situation...you can use `text-indent` instead of `font-size:0` it will work perfectly

Comment: The #container must have no white spaces. The #text must have text. If I set the container with `text-indent:-9999px;` it disappears (unwanted behavior); If I set the #text with `text-indent:-9999px;` it disappears (unwanted behavior aswell). The goal of this question is let the second image (blue background) looking like the first one (yellow background).